# Plesk: SSL Issue on shared IP Hosting with multiple Domains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, plesk, shared-hosting, multiple-domains

this one is driving me mad - hopefully anyone of you can help.

I ordered a cloud server with intention of running multiple customer sites on one server/one ip. Everything is working fine so far, but Im having troubles with SSL.

I added 2 Domains (Domain a, Domain b) via Plesk Panel and installed basic ssl certificates which are working perfectly fine. Both Domains can be accessed via https:// and in the broswer both certificates are shown as valid / secure

Problem: Im getting SSL Issues / Warnings when connecting to the domains mailboxes -> to secure the Plesk Panel a self-signed Certificate was pre-installed.

When I exchange the Plesk self-signed certificate to a certificate for Domain a, Domain a mailboxes are working perfectly fine - but not for Domain b. (obviously). What certificate do I need to install to secure the Plesk Panel and which does not cause any problems with all underlying Domains & their mailboxes?

Will creating a certificate for the servers IP address will do the trick? Is this accepted, even possible or will it result in another warnings? If yes, do I need to create a certificate for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx or xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443?

Or is there any other option for running multiple domains on one shared ip?

Any help/guidance is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Apache?  You'll need to use SNI.  The issue is that the URL is part of the encrypted data, so it used to be impossible to then decrypt selectively using more than one cert on the same IP address (which is really the only unencrypted bit:  The IP and port...).  I'm no expert in SNI but back in the day I know some old versions of IE (like 6?) wouldn't play nicely with it, but unless you need to account for that, I think you have to make sure SNI is turned on.  There's a good overview at Digicert: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm.

Comment: yes, im using apache. SNI is turned on and both domain ssl certificates (domain a & domain b) are working. I only get the error/warning when connecting to mailboxes because of the plesk panel server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like mail.domainb.com or autodiscover.domainb.com for mailbox? Then make sure you have valid SSL certificate for them also not only for mail domain. As far as I know you would not be able to get third-party certificate on IP addresses.

Sorry if I have guessed wrong.